# How to set precision of LocalDateTime to nanoseconds in Java.time?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

According to the [java.time documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), java.time should be able to present a LocalDateTime or LocalTime with nanoseconds precision, but when I run `LocalDateTime.now()` and print out, it only shows 3 digits instead of 9.

Like this:

```
2016-08-11T22:17:35.031
```

Is there a way to get a higher precision?

Comment: How are you printing it out? And why do you need higher precision -- the computer clock is probably not more accurate anyways.

Comment: I am using `System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now())` to print it out. I just started to learn Java, and is experimenting around a bit and got stuck on this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am assuming you are just using `LocalDateTime.toString()`, in which case [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--) reads:

> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

If you want additional digits to show up, even if they are zeroes, you will need to create a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and use that instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS");

System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter));
```

Further, `LocalDateTime.now()` uses the system default [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) which is only guaranteed to have millisecond precision, but can use a higher resolution clock if one is available. It's possible that your platform doesn't have a clock that is available to the JRE with a higher resolution than milliseconds.

**Update** - You can also create a `LocalDateTime` with `LocalDateTime.of()` to verify that nanoseconds are stored and will be included in the return value of the default `LocalDateTime.toString()` method:

```
LocalDateTime when =
    LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.AUGUST, 12, 9, 38, 12, 123456789);

System.out.println(when);
```

The output of the above would be:

```
2016-08-12T09:38:12.123456789
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LocaleDateTime.now().getNano()`

You are just doing `System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now())`. This uses `toString()` method which doesn't show nanoseconds if they are zero.