# Convert given Time to nanosecond precision using java

Tags: java, time

my code:

```
String timeColonPattern = "HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS";             
DateTimeFormatter timeColonFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeColonPattern);
LocalTime colonTime = LocalTime.parse("09:30:23.187235");
```

I want "09:30:23.187235" to be converted into nanosecond precision. colonTime is same as 09:30:23.187235 but I want it to be converted into 09:30:23.187235000. i.e. It should add zeros if the digits after decimal is less than 9. Any suggestion how can I achieve that?

Comment: if you do that, you don't add precision, you just pretend to add precision. What you are adding is hardcoded 0's, that's a different thing

Comment: `LocalTime` has nanosecond precision. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: If the time is in milliseconds or microseconds then I want it to add extra zeros but it is not adding extra zeros.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/tCMwHw

Comment: I didn't use .format(). Sorry. Now i am getting desired output. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set precision of LocalDateTime to nanoseconds in Java.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905887/how-to-set-precision-of-localdatetime-to-nanoseconds-in-java-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) already has [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) precision. If you want to have this precision being output, do not use the `.SSSSSSSSS` pattern, but use `.nnnnnnnnn`:

```
LocalTime colonTime = LocalTime.parse("09:30:23.187235");
System.out.println(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn")
                     .format(colonTime)
);
```

See this [code run in IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/7FzmG6).

> 09:30:23.187235000

See all possible patterns see the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

Comment: I didn't use .format(). Sorry. Now i am getting desired output. Thanks

Comment: `SSSSSSSSS` works too. The important part is just using a formatter for formatting when printing.